# js change structure of an json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array like this:

```
let array =  [
      {1: {
        "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "22458"
      }},
      {2: {
        "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "30585"
      }},
      {3: {
        "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "49536"
      }}
    ]
```

But I need this like this:

```
let array =  [
      {
        "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "22458"
      },
      {
        "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "30585"
      },
      {
        "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "49536"
      }
    ]
```

I tried to change this like:

```
array.forEach(function(e){
          newData.push(e);
        });
```

But this does not work. Push is not supported.

Next try was:

```
let newData = {};
        array.forEach(function(e){
          newData = {...newData, ...e};
        });
```

No success. Any ideas how to get the result?

Comment: You initial array structure will return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

Comment: Sorry, I changed the first array now.

Comment: Your updated input appears to be an array of objects where you want to extract nested object values. Do you ever have multiple properties on any of the objects in the array? Should they all be extracted into the flattened array?

Comment: Yes, they have multiple properties and the should be also in the flattened array. I only want to loos the keys of the first level.

Answer (score 3):

You could get a flat array of values of the objects.

```js
let array = [{ 1: { date: "2014-04-23 00:00:00", volumetrie: "22458" } }, { 2: { date: "2014-05-02 00:00:00", volumetrie: "30585" } }, { 3: { date: "2014-03-27 00:00:00", volumetrie: "49536" } }],
    result = array.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh, now **that** is nice.

Comment: this delivers an absolut flat thing. I want 3 separate objects in the array at the end.

Comment: @FishWave, with the given data and just a single object in each item, you get three objects.

Comment: @FishWave - Click "Run code snippet," it doesn't deliver something completely flat.

Comment: TIL `smooshMap` never happened 

Comment: @Damon - But I understand it was close-ish. ;-)

Comment: woah this answer is  powerful!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha yikes. I don't know the gory details, I stopped following it after the buzz in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the objects in your array always have one enumerable property, you can do it with `map` and `Object.values`:

```
array = array.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0]);
```

Live Example:

```js
let array =  [
  {1: {
    "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "22458"
  }},
  {2: {
    "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "30585"
  }},
  {3: {
    "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "49536"
  }}
];
array = array.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But see also [Nina's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60935721/157247) using `flatMap`, which is just beautiful.

Comment: was about to post same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map every item in the array to a new item, which is the value of the first key of the original item:

```js
let array =  [
  { 1: {
    "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "22458"
  }},
  { 2: {
    "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "30585"
  }},
  { 3: {
    "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
    "volumetrie": "49536"
  }}
];

let formatted = array.map(v => { for (let k in v) return v[k]; });

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: With this code, I get only the first entry of each of the three objects back...

Comment: I assumed from the data given that there's only one entry per array item

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const oldData = [
    {1: {
        "date": "2014-04-23 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "22458"
    }},
    {2: {
        "date": "2014-05-02 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "30585"
    }},
    {3: {
        "date": "2014-03-27 00:00:00",
        "volumetrie": "49536"
    }}
];
const newData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
    newData[i] = oldData[i][i+1];
}
```